# Ruby regular expression error

Tags: ruby, regex

When running a ruby script with regex,

```
s = object.value.gsub(/(\A[\s\xA0]*|[\s\xA0]*\Z)/n, '')
```

Got error

```
invalid multibyte escape: /(\A[\s\xA0]*|[\s\xA0]*\Z)/ (SyntaxError)
```

Any idea why?  Ruby version `2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\xHH` syntax is only valid for UTF-8 characters `\x00` to `\x7F`. `\x80` to `\xFF` are valid in US-ASCII encoding, but not `UTF-8`; to use higher characters in UTF-8, use `\uHHHH`. Thus, these all work:

```
/\u00A0/

/#{"\\xA0".encode('US-ASCII')}/

Regexp.new("\\xA0".encode('US-ASCII'))

# encoding: US-ASCII
/\xA0/
```

although they do different things, depending on what encoding you are matching. For example:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
Regexp.new("\\xA0".encode('US-ASCII')) =~ "\u00A0"
# => Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)
```